# Import and Export for CSV are both broken in Mathematica

Tags: arrays, file, file-io, csv, wolfram-mathematica

Consider the following 2 by 2 array:

```
x = {{"a b c", "1,2,3"}, {"i \"comma-heart\" you", "i \",heart\" u, too"}}
```

If we Export that to CSV and then Import it again we don't get the same thing back:

```
Import[Export["tmp.csv", d]]
```

Looking at tmp.csv it's clear that the Export didn't work, since the quotes are not escaped properly.

According to the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) which I presume is summarized correctly on [Wikipedia's entry on CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values), the right way to export the above array is as follows:

```
a b c, "1,2,3"
"i ""heart"" you", "i "",heart"" u, too"
```

Importing the above does not yield the original array either.
So Import is broken as well.

I've reported these bugs to support@wolfram.com but I'm wondering if others have workarounds in the meantime.

One workaround is to just use TSV instead of CSV.
I tested the above with TSV and it seems to work (even with tabs embedded in the entries of the array).

Comment: If that upsets you, try Import[Export["string.csv", x, "CSV"]] which will probably ruin your day.  Sorry.

Comment: @High Performance Mark: I tried it but don't see a difference when using the explicit "CSV" parameter.  What did you mean?

Comment: Response from Wolfram: Thank you for taking the time to send us this report. I have forwarded your examples to our development group. 

The recommended solution to this problem is to use a different 
format. 

We apologize for any inconvenience caused by this problem. 

I included your contact information so that you can be notified
when this has been resolved.

Comment: Btw. still present in Mathematica 10. It's been almost 6 years!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of TSV, another workaround is to use a different delimiter:

```
In[26]:= str = ExportString[x, "CSV", "TextDelimiters"->"'"];
Out[26]= "'a b c','1,2,3'
'i \"comma-heart\" you','i \",heart\" u, too'"

In[27]:= y = ImportString[str, "CSV", "TextDelimiters"->"'"]
Out[27]= {{"a b c", "1,2,3"}, {"i \"comma-heart\" you", "i \",heart\" u, too"}}

In[28]:= x == y
Out[28]= True
```

Note that `Import`/`Export` and `ImportString`/`ExportString` take the same options, the latter functions just read/write strings instead of files.

You could also use one of the other tabular/scientific data formats that Mathematica supports, like XLS, ODS, HDF, HDF5, CDF, FITS, etc.

- [Tabular & Spreadsheet Formats](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/TabularAndSpreadsheetFormats.html)
- [Scientific & Medical Data Formats](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/ScientificAndMedicalDataFormats.html)
- [WDX Format](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/WDX.html) (Wolfram Data eXchange format)

You might also find some of them faster since some of them are binary and there is thus no textual parsing to be done. It all depends on your application and what the file is used for outside of Mathematica.

Comment: Good idea. Though I imagine we could concoct an example with both escaped single and double quotes that would make your version break the same way as mine.

Comment: Of course; such is the nature of workarounds =) You could also use one of the other tabular/scientific data formats that Mathematica supports, like XLS, ODS, HDF, HDF5, CDF, FITS, etc. You might also find some of them faster since some of them are binary and there is thus no textual parsing to be done. It all depends on your application and what the file is used for outside of Mathematica.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Good thoughts; you should make that part of your answer!